# Conditional auto deploy based on git tag in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

Helo,

I'm using Bamboo to deploy a Java webapp project that's triggered by git repo push. My requirement is to deploy based on conditions,

1. "branch is pushed" and
2. "new commit is tagged as some value"

Is it possible to be done using existing plugin? If I have to implement it manually, is it possible? how to?

Answer (score 3):

There may be simple and more direct ways of doing this with the latest Atlassian Bamboo major release (version 5, see https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/deploy). I would certainly embrace some additional automation/deployment workflows around these types of features, but I implemented something akin to what you're asking for without plugins and have been using it quite successfully for eight months.

Here's how it works:

1. We merge to a `testing` branch which executes a suite of unit, integration, functional, and workflow tests, and builds various pieces of documentation. This is like your (1): "branch is pushed"
2. We run a second manual plan which pulls the latest `testing` branch, tags it, and pushes the tag.
3. Our third step is to run a deployment plan which deploys the latest tag.

I think step **(1)** and **(3)** will vary widely between applications. Step **(2)** however may hit on what you're after. Here's the details regarding that plan and its associated task:

1. Checkout the `testing` branch, *Force Clean Build* is enabled
2. Use an inline script to add a remote repository. E.g., a GitHub example:

   1. `git remote add origin git@github.com:/repo.git || exit 0`
3. Use the `git` excutable with arguments `pull origin testing` to ensure we're consistent with the upstream repository
4. Use the `git` excutable with arguments `fetch --all --tags` to get the latest tags from all repositories
5. Use a `bash` executable with a custom script to change the version of our codebase to what the tag will be named.
6. Use the `git` excutable with arguments `push origin --tags` to push the tag created in the previous step.

The custom script mentioned in **(5)** looks like this:

```
    scripts/version.sh ${DATE}
    git commit -m "bumped version"
    git tag -af "${DATE}" -m "Build server tagged ${DATE}"
```

For completeness, I'm using `|| exit 1` everywhere within scripts to make sure they fail-fast but left these out for brevity.

**tl;dr** No plugins support what you're asking for to my knowledge. It is possible. The *how* will vary for you, hopefully what I've set forth shows that.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful though it's an old question. Currently I have done similar using raw bash scripts and registered them as commands abilities in Bamboo, which is quite straight-forward and time-saving. Many of detailed tasks in my work are done this way though don't have much UI.